# Using Vagrant on cloud CI services

Tags: continuous-integration, vagrant, travis-ci, circleci, scrutinizer

Are there any cloud CI services that allow Vagrant VMs to run using VirtualBox as a provider?

Early investigation shows this seems not to be possible with Travis CI or Circle CI, although the vagrant-aws plugin allows for the use of AWS servers as a Vagrant provider.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many CI services are not allowing to run Vagrant via LXC or Virtualbox as it will require nested virtualization (running VM in VM) or a pure bare metal server provisioned for you.

Current 2021 (updated) situation:

- Github Actions can do it.
- Travis was able to run Vagrant with some workarounds.
- AppVeyor allows running VirtualBox (non-free plans).
- You can't under CodeShip
- [You can't under CircleCI](https://github.com/fgrehm/vagrant-lxc/issues/339)
- Don't know about other CI services, will investigate further.

I hope during the time we'll see CI services allowing to run Vagrant with Virtualbox or LXC, but for now Docker (with its limitations) is the only option.

---

Personally, I would be happy to use it for integration tests against different platforms/linux distros via [Test-Kitchen CI](http://kitchen.ci/) or similar.

Comment: AppVeyor allows to run VirtualBox.

Comment: This answer isn't true any more, since from beginning of 2020 Travis was able to run Vagrant - and now also GitHub Actions is. AppVeyor doesn't support Vagrant fully in the free plans, since nested virtualization is missing there.

Answer (score 6):

**Update January 2021**: [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) also supports Vagrant - and [Vagrant/VirtualBox are both installed out-of-the-box in the MacOS environment](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/433) ([not on Linux](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/183) or Windows currently!). See the [possible environments here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments). Therefore I created a fully comprehensible example project at: https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-github-actions

**1.: Create a [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-github-actions/blob/main/Vagrantfile)** (and you're not limited to libvirt as with Travis, you have a full VirtualBox environment with nested virtualization working on GitHub Actions!) like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1804"

    config.vm.define 'ubuntu'

    # Prevent SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate errors
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
end
```

**2.: Create a GitHub Actions workflow** like this [vagrant-up.yml](https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/vagrant-up.yml) inside the `.github/workflows` directory in your repository:

```
name: vagrant-up

on: [push]

jobs:
  vagrant-up:
    runs-on: macos-10.15

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Run vagrant up
      run: vagrant up

    - name: ssh into box after boot
      run: vagrant ssh -c "echo 'hello world!'"
```

You can even [add caching for the Vagran boxes](https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/vagrant-up.yml#L12), this will safe you some seconds :)

---

**Early 2020:**

**TravisCI is now able to run Vagrant finally!** Thanks to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ansible-community/molecule-vagrant/issues/8#issuecomment-589902704) I learned about [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/) and KVM, which could be used together with the [vagrant-libvirt Plugin](https://github.com/vagrant-libvirt/vagrant-libvirt) to run Vagrant boxes on TravisCI.

An example TravisCI `.travis.yml` should look somehow like that:

```
---
dist: bionic
language: python

install:
# Install libvrt & KVM
- sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y bridge-utils dnsmasq-base ebtables libvirt-bin libvirt-dev qemu-kvm qemu-utils ruby-dev

# Download Vagrant & Install Vagrant package
- sudo wget -nv https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/2.2.7/vagrant_2.2.7_x86_64.deb
- sudo dpkg -i vagrant_2.2.7_x86_64.deb

# Vagrant correctly installed?
- vagrant --version

# Install vagrant-libvirt Vagrant plugin
- sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-libvirt

script:
- sudo vagrant up --provider=libvirt
- sudo vagrant ssh -c "echo 'hello world!'"
```

With the help of the [`generic` Vagrant Box images from Vagrant Cloud](https://app.vagrantup.com/generic) you can also establish a workflow of using Vagrant + libvirt + KVM on Travis and Vagrant + VirtualBox on your local machine, if you like:

[image]

I created a fully working and 100% comprehensible example project here: https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-travisci-libvrt

Comment: Awesome news! Thanks a lot for heads-up sharing this 

Answer (score 0):

[AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/) runs Vagrant using VirtualBox as a provider. Furthermore, you can use other providers like libvirt or Hyper-v.

Updated:
[Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) is another option. Only [Mac OS environment](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md) has nested virtualization enabled. An example is [here](https://github.com/danielmenezesbr/vagrant-github-actions) and [here](https://github.com/danielmenezesbr/vagrant-github-actions/runs/1093185440?check_suite_focus=true).