# Using Vagrant on GitHub Actions (ideally incl. VirtualBox)

Tags: continuous-integration, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox, github-actions

I know [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615201/4964553) that it's possible to spin up and run Vagrant Boxes on TravisCI using `libvirt` instead of VirtualBox.

Is that also possible with GitHub Actions? Since we're moving everything away from TravisCI because of [the new pricing model](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2020-11-02-travis-ci-new-billing), we also need to switch our Vagrant-based test cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [this is possible using the `macos-10.15`](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/433) (which is [currently the `macos-latest`) environment](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments). You could also try to go with `macos-11.0`, but there [currently seems to be no stable VirtualBox release for Big Sur](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/433#issuecomment-765180496). I created a small example project at https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-github-actions

Assume you have a [Vagrantfile](https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-github-actions/blob/main/Vagrantfile) inside your repo like this:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1804"

    config.vm.define 'ubuntu'

    # Prevent SharedFoldersEnableSymlinksCreate errors
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
end
```

Then you add a GitHub Action workflow like [vagrant-up.yml](https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-github-actions/blob/main/.github/workflows/vagrant-up.yml) inside your `.github/workflows` folder like this:

```
name: vagrant-up

on: [push]

jobs:
  vagrant-up:
    runs-on: macos-10.15

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Cache Vagrant boxes
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: ~/.vagrant.d/boxes
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-vagrant-${{ hashFiles('Vagrantfile') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-vagrant-

    - name: Run vagrant up
      run: vagrant up

    - name: ssh into box after boot
      run: vagrant ssh -c "echo 'hello world!'"
```

You could even leave out [the caching action](https://github.com/actions/cache) - I simply added it here to show what's possible. It'll save you some seconds, which depends on the VagrantBox you're using.

The GitHub Actions implementation for running Vagrant is **much** easier then [the TravisCI counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60615201/4964553), because you don't need to install Vagrant or VirtualBox - and you also don't need to switch to libvirt. Just use the box you want from https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search which is pretty cool.

Comment: I get `vagrant: command not found` in November of 2021 on `macos-latest`.

Comment: According to [the GitHub Actions Virtual Environment docs for `macos-latest`](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/macos/macos-10.15-Readme.md) (which is macOS 10.15 today, not BigSur) `vagrant` should be still available.

Comment: this is a good point but here's an example workflow run where it's not available on macos latest (this used to work, might be a pathing issue, not sure).  Can see the workflow action syntax since it's public. https://github.com/a2f0/dotfiles/runs/4184671229?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: In my example project there's also an ongoing discussion about macOS 11 Vagrant support https://github.com/jonashackt/vagrant-github-actions/issues/2

Comment: Hi @jonashackt is there any better way today ? or is your repo still the reference for such usage of Vagrant ? In order to use Vagrant for Linux, we still have to use `macos` systems on GitHub Actions ?

Comment: I've found this issue describing that now it was possible to use nested virtualization under Linux/Windows GitHub Actions images, but I haven't given it a try myself : https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/183 
EDIT: Actually, it is only available for large runner and not normal runner so it's not free I believe.
EDIT 2: A workaround would be to use this : https://actuated.dev/blog/kvm-in-github-actions

Comment: Yeah the problem is, that nested virtualization is normally a "business" feature and thus not for free. An alternative would be to use libvrt / KVM as described in the [Early 2020 section of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60380518/4964553).